# no circle in top right corner if value is null

Tags: css

i want to put number at top right conner of icon.

But when without number (or value=""), i need remove red dot.

My html:

```
<a href="www.abc.com">
<div class="image-wrapper">
<img class="btn-image" src="https://i.imgur.com/GtP6s3j.png"/><span class="btn-cnt" id="counter1">123</span>
<div class="btn-text">
Number
</div>
</div>
</a>
```

My css:

```
.image-wrapper { text-align: center; display: inline-block; position: relative; }
.image-wrapper .btn-image { max-width: 75px; max-height: 75px; }
.image-wrapper .btn-text { display: block; }
.image-wrapper .btn-cnt { position: absolute; top: -5px; right: -5px; background: #f00; color: #fff; padding: 5px; border: 0; border-radius: 50%; font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.2em; }
```

My full code: https://jsfiddle.net/bvotcode/szwc2b5d/4/

Please help remove red dot, if without number or value = "" or only space on top

Thank in advance

Please see image
[image]

Comment: Hi for handle this is better use javascript.

Comment: You can make use of  [`:empty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty) selector. For example: https://jsfiddle.net/jx51o7q0/

Comment: You can also make use of attribute selector like `span#counter1[value=""] { display: none; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that the span will have **no text at all in it** (which means no white space even) then you can use pseudo-class :empty.

```css
.image-wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.image-wrapper .btn-image {
  max-width: 75px;
  max-height: 75px;
}

.image-wrapper .btn-text {
  display: block;
}

.image-wrapper .btn-cnt {
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  right: -5px;
  background: #f00;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.image-wrapper .btn-cnt:empty {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<a href="www.abc.com">
  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <img class="btn-image" src="https://i.imgur.com/GtP6s3j.png" /><span class="btn-cnt" id="counter1"></span>
    <div class="btn-text">
      Number
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

However, the question has this phrase: 'or only space'. If this means there might be a space character in there, see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty)

> The :empty CSS pseudo-class represents any element that has no children. Children can be either element nodes or text (including whitespace).

This means that if a space is put in the span instead of a number, empty will not work.